# Parsing Each Row Individually

Tags: android, parsing, jsoup

Hi Guys I am trying to Parse Each Row on a table individually and then putting  the content of it in a string. Like this page http://reviews.cnet.com/consoles/sony-playstation-3-60gb/4507-10109_7-31355103.html

My goal is to parse each value of every row not including the label for example

Memory| 60 GB
CPU| 8 core

etc.

So I need to parse only the value of every spec in the table then put the value of each spec in a separate string

So I would need a string with the name memory that has the parsed value from the URL and a string with the name CPU that has the parse value extracted from the URL and so on.
How can I procceed?

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://reviews.cnet.com/consoles/sony-playstation-3-60gb/4507-10109_731355103.html").get();for (Element table : doc.select("table.tablehead")) {
    for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
        Elements tds = row.select("td");
        if (tds.size() > 6) {
            System.out.println(tds.get(0).text() + ":" + tds.get(1).text());
   String CPU = row.text();
    }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look at [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)

Comment: Html, I am trying to get the table from the site

Comment: Well tried Jsoup but I am having issues getting it to work right. Here is my code

Comment: Did you add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to your `AndroidManifest.xml`?